# Calculating biological growth of doubling cells

Tags: exponential-function, biology

> For some kinds of experiments, biologists use isolated cells grown in
> culture. Cells differ significantly in their cell doubling times (one
> cell dividing into two cells).
>
> - Plant cells can double every 18 hr
> - Animal cells (matrix requiring) can double every 18 hr
> - Animal cells (nonmatrix requiring)can double every 14 hr
> - Yeast cells can double every 2 hr
> - Bacteria cells can double every 20 min
>
> Based on the above information, if you start with one cell of each
> type, how many cells of each type would you have after one week?

### Update:

I believe I can answer this the following way:

> - Plant cells can double every 18 hr

18/24 = 3/4 day.
7days/ 3/4 =28/3 = 9 1/3
I disregarded the 1/3, and used the 9 doublings for 2^9= 512 cells

> - Animal cells (matrix requiring) can double every 18 hr

again same as above, I got 512 cells

Am I on the right track? Please help!

Comment: there are $24\times 7$ hours in a week, divide this with the hours you mentioned and what you get, say $x$, $2^x$ will be the answers.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a biologist, but if I understand the problem correctly this seem to be an *exponential growth* problem. I believe we need to use the [simple doubling time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_time) formula: $2^{\frac{d}{t}}$

*where*

- $d$: *doubling period* (time it takes for object to double in number)
- $t:$ *time*

> Plant cells can double every 18 hr:

$=2^{\frac{(24*7)}{18}} = 2^{\frac{168}{18}} = 2^{9.3333}= 645.07$

> Animal cells (matrix requiring) can double every 18 hr:

$=2^{\frac{(24*7)}{18}} = 2^{\frac{168}{18}} = 2^{9.3333}= 645.07$

> Animal cells (nonmatrix requiring)can double every 14 hr:

$=2^{\frac{(24*7)}{14}} = 2^{\frac{168}{14}} = 2^{12}= 4096$

> Yeast cells can double every 2 hr:

$=2^{\frac{(24*7)}{2}} = 2^{\frac{168}{2}} = 2^{84}= 1.9342813e+25$

> Bacteria cells can double every 20 min:

So, notice that $20$ minutes = $0.333333$ hours:

$=2^{\frac{(24*7)}{0.333333}} = 2^{\frac{168}{0.333333}} = 2^{504.05}= 5.423645e+151$

*What is **matrix** and **non-matrix** requiring? Could you provide a definition from the source?*

Also review [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285296/population-growth?rq=1), it maybe related?

Comment: What does that mean? Am I going to sleep in the street tonight?

Comment: I believe no one sleeps in the streets, since there are shelters for the homeless :)

Comment: -IDidn'tDothat: I Did do That!

Comment: Can you please share my other question?